# sound manipulation with program : where should I start learning?

Tags: signal-processing

I want to develop an application which could process recorded sound / taken audio file and manipulate it's sound. Where should I start to learn.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain recording from microphone using HTML5 you can start [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/).

For signal processing the good starting point can be MATLAB, if you have access to it.
Python and numpy package have very good opensource tools as well.

I would start by learning how to load a `wav` or `mp3` file into MATLAB or Python (I really recommend IPython and IPython notebook) and learning how to make a Fourier analysis of this signal, then proceed with spectrograms and then try to implement different effects.

Other interesting software to look at are: MaxDSP (not free), PureData (free).

If you have more specific questions - ask. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Before manipulating existing sound - I would first get comfortable understanding audio itself - lookup PCM (pulse code modulation) - write some code which populates an array with a curve between values of -1 to +1 ... say using the sin function - then output this as a WAV file - download the audio utility called :  Audacity which is a swiss army knife for audio processing - do not get caught up with fancy libraries until you get some Ah Ha moments with your hand rolled code - to playback/record audio take a look at :  web audio API / OpenAL / OpenSL depending on your choice of platform web / laptop / mobile - welcome aboard